# Checking convergence of 2-layer neural network in python

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am working with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_prime(x):
    return sigmoid(x)*(1.0-sigmoid(x))

def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)

def tanh_prime(x):
    return 1.0 - x**2


class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, layers, activation='tanh'):
        if activation == 'sigmoid':
            self.activation = sigmoid
            self.activation_prime = sigmoid_prime
        elif activation == 'tanh':
            self.activation = tanh
            self.activation_prime = tanh_prime

        # Set weights
        self.weights = []
        # layers = [2,2,1]
        # range of weight values (-1,1)
        # input and hidden layers - random((2+1, 2+1)) : 3 x 3
        for i in range(1, len(layers) - 1):
            r = 2*np.random.random((layers[i-1] + 1, layers[i] + 1)) -1
            self.weights.append(r)
        # output layer - random((2+1, 1)) : 3 x 1
        r = 2*np.random.random( (layers[i] + 1, layers[i+1])) - 1
        self.weights.append(r)

    def fit(self, X, y, learning_rate=0.2, epochs=100000):
        # Add column of ones to X
        # This is to add the bias unit to the input layer
        ones = np.atleast_2d(np.ones(X.shape[0]))
        X = np.concatenate((ones.T, X), axis=1)

        for k in range(epochs):
            if k % 10000 == 0: print 'epochs:', k

            i = np.random.randint(X.shape[0])
            a = [X[i]]

            for l in range(len(self.weights)):
                    dot_value = np.dot(a[l], self.weights[l])
                    activation = self.activation(dot_value)
                    a.append(activation)
            # output layer
            error = y[i] - a[-1]
            deltas = [error * self.activation_prime(a[-1])]

            # we need to begin at the second to last layer 
            # (a layer before the output layer)
            for l in range(len(a) - 2, 0, -1): 
                deltas.append(deltas[-1].dot(self.weights[l].T)*self.activation_prime(a[l]))

            # reverse
            # [level3(output)->level2(hidden)]  => [level2(hidden)->level3(output)]
            deltas.reverse()

            # backpropagation
            # 1. Multiply its output delta and input activation 
            #    to get the gradient of the weight.
            # 2. Subtract a ratio (percentage) of the gradient from the weight.
            for i in range(len(self.weights)):
                layer = np.atleast_2d(a[i])
                delta = np.atleast_2d(deltas[i])
                self.weights[i] += learning_rate * layer.T.dot(delta)

    def predict(self, x): 
        a = np.concatenate((np.ones(1).T, np.array(x)), axis=0)      
        for l in range(0, len(self.weights)):
            a = self.activation(np.dot(a, self.weights[l]))
        return a

if __name__ == '__main__':

    nn = NeuralNetwork([2,2,1])

    X = np.array([[0, 0],
                  [0, 1],
                  [1, 0],
                  [1, 1]])

    y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])

    nn.fit(X, y)

    for e in X:
        print(e,nn.predict(e))
```

While this converges well and fast when using the tanh, it does converge much slower when using the sigmoid ( `in def __init__(self, layers, activation='tanh')` change `tanh` to `sigmoid` ).
I cannot find why that is. How do I improve the implementation for the sigmoid?

Comment: Are you interested in reviews on aspects of the code unrelated to the sigmoid implementation?

Comment: Of course I am!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The reasons for the speed discrepancy

1. The reason for the differences in timing are because evaluating `sigmoid_prime()` takes far longer than `tanh_prime()`.  You can see this if you use a line profiler such as the [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) module.
2. Is `tanh_prime()` supposed to be the derivative of `tanh()`? If so, you might want to double-check your formula.  The derivative of `tanh(x)` is `1. - tanh(x)**2`, not `1. - x**2`.
3. In fact, if you use the the actual definition of the derivative of `tanh()`, the timings become much more similar.

   ```
   def tanh_prime_alt(x):
       return 1 - tanh(x)**2

   foo = np.random.rand(10000)
   %timeit -n 100 tanh_prime(foo)
   %timeit -n 100 tanh_prime_alt(foo)
   %timeit -n 100 sigmoid_prime(foo)

   100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 µs per loop
   100 loops, best of 3: 116 µs per loop
   100 loops, best of 3: 279 µs per loop
   ```

   So with this alternate `tanh_prime()`, the sigmoid method is now only 2× slower, not 20× slower.  I should emphasize that (a) I don't know enough about neural networks to know if `1. - x**2` is an appropriate expression or approximation to the actual derivative of `tanh()`, but if it is in fact OK, then (b) the reason that `activation = 'tanh'` is so much faster is because of this approximation/error.
4. The remaining 2× difference is because in your factored expression of `sigmoid_prime()`, you are needlessly evaluating `sigmoid()` twice.  I'd instead do this:

   ```
   def sigmoid_prime_alt(x):
       sig_x = sigmoid(x)
       return sig_x - sig_x**2
   ```

   As expected, this speeds things up two-fold relative to your original definition.

   ```
   foo = np.random.rand(10000)
   %timeit -n 100 sigmoid_prime(foo)
   %timeit -n 100 sigmoid_prime_alt(foo)

   100 loops, best of 3: 248 µs per loop
   100 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop
   ```
5. Since the `sigmoid()` function and the `tanh()` function are related by `tanh(x) = 2 * sigmoid(2*x) - 1`, i.e. `sigmoid(x) = (1 + tanh(x/2.))/2`, then ***iff*** you are OK with the weird `1 - x**2` approximation for `tanh_prime()`, you should be able to work out a similar approximation for `sigmoid_prime()`.
6. You might be interested in the [`autograd`](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) module, which provides a generalized capability to compute symbolic derivatives of most NumPy code.

### Other comments

These comments aren't a thorough review, but just some things I noticed.

1. Why are your `weights` Python lists instead of NumPy arrays?  If you're already using NumPy, you might as well use it wherever you can.
2. You probably don't need the `for l in range(len(self.weights)):` loop, do you?  Can't you use NumPy array slicing and the matrix capabilities of `np.dot()` to replace this loop?
3. If you are going to loop, you don't need to do `for l in range(len(self.weights))` and then reference `self.weights[l]`.  You can do `for weight in self.weights:` and then reference `weight` in your loop code, for example.
4. Write some [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for your functions please!